# Error: Generator "prisma-field-encryption" failed

Tags: database, encryption, generator, prisma

I installed the following package for Prisma:
https://github.com/47ng/prisma-field-encryption

I went through the steps, but I got stuck at the migration part and couldn't find a solution or a similar topic.

I specified the second generator to encrypt data migration, as described in the description:

```
generator client {
   provider = "prisma-client-js"
   engineType = "binary"
}

generator fieldEncryptionMigrations {
   provider = "prisma-field-encryption"
   output = "./data-migrations"
   // Optionally opt-in to concurrent model migration.
   // Since this can cause timeouts and performance issues,
   // it's off by default, and models are updated sequentially.
   concurrently = true
}
```

After running the `prisma migrate dev` command, I encounter the error that:

```
Error: Generator "prisma-field-encryption" failed:
/bin/sh: 1: prisma-field-encryption: not found
```

I've already tried reinstalling the package, but it's installed correctly as new data is encrypted perfectly.

My Prisma version is 5.0.0

Comment: What does this have to do with the Scheme programming language?